# Error installing python package using pip

Tags: python, django, pip

I am trying to install a python package using pip in linux mint but keep getting this error message. Anyone know how to fix this?

```
alex@alex-Satellite-C660D ~ $ pip install django-registration-redux
Downloading/unpacking django-registration-redux
  Downloading django-registration-redux-1.1.tar.gz (63kB): 63kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_alex/django-registration-redux/setup.py) egg_info for package django-registration-redux

    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
Installing collected packages: django-registration-redux
  Running setup.py install for django-registration-redux

    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
    error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/test_app': Permission denied
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3.4 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_alex/django-registration-redux/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-qi55qyaf-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib

creating build/lib/test_app

copying test_app/__init__.py -> build/lib/test_app

copying test_app/models.py -> build/lib/test_app

copying test_app/urls_simple.py -> build/lib/test_app

copying test_app/settings.py -> build/lib/test_app

copying test_app/urls_default.py -> build/lib/test_app

copying test_app/settings_test.py -> build/lib/test_app

creating build/lib/registration

copying registration/users.py -> build/lib/registration

copying registration/views.py -> build/lib/registration

copying registration/signals.py -> build/lib/registration

copying registration/__init__.py -> build/lib/registration

copying registration/forms.py -> build/lib/registration

copying registration/auth_urls.py -> build/lib/registration

copying registration/urls.py -> build/lib/registration

copying registration/models.py -> build/lib/registration

copying registration/admin.py -> build/lib/registration

creating build/lib/registration/management

copying registration/management/__init__.py -> build/lib/registration/management

creating build/lib/registration/tests

copying registration/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib/registration/tests

copying registration/tests/forms.py -> build/lib/registration/tests

copying registration/tests/urls.py -> build/lib/registration/tests

copying registration/tests/simple_backend.py -> build/lib/registration/tests

copying registration/tests/models.py -> build/lib/registration/tests

copying registration/tests/default_backend.py -> build/lib/registration/tests

creating build/lib/registration/backends

copying registration/backends/__init__.py -> build/lib/registration/backends

creating build/lib/registration/management/commands

copying registration/management/commands/__init__.py -> build/lib/registration/management/commands

copying registration/management/commands/cleanupregistration.py -> build/lib/registration/management/commands

creating build/lib/registration/backends/default

copying registration/backends/default/views.py -> build/lib/registration/backends/default

copying registration/backends/default/__init__.py -> build/lib/registration/backends/default

copying registration/backends/default/urls.py -> build/lib/registration/backends/default

creating build/lib/registration/backends/simple

copying registration/backends/simple/views.py -> build/lib/registration/backends/simple

copying registration/backends/simple/__init__.py -> build/lib/registration/backends/simple

copying registration/backends/simple/urls.py -> build/lib/registration/backends/simple

running egg_info

writing top-level names to django_registration_redux.egg-info/top_level.txt

writing django_registration_redux.egg-info/PKG-INFO

writing dependency_links to django_registration_redux.egg-info/dependency_links.txt

warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found



reading manifest file 'django_registration_redux.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'

no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'

writing manifest file 'django_registration_redux.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

creating build/lib/registration/locale

creating build/lib/registration/locale/ar

creating build/lib/registration/locale/ar/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/ar/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo -> build/lib/registration/locale/ar/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/ar/LC_MESSAGES/django.po -> build/lib/registration/locale/ar/LC_MESSAGES

creating build/lib/registration/locale/bg

creating build/lib/registration/locale/bg/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/bg/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo -> build/lib/registration/locale/bg/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/bg/LC_MESSAGES/django.po -> build/lib/registration/locale/bg/LC_MESSAGES

creating build/lib/registration/locale/ca

creating build/lib/registration/locale/ca/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/ca/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo -> build/lib/registration/locale/ca/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/ca/LC_MESSAGES/django.po -> build/lib/registration/locale/ca/LC_MESSAGES

creating build/lib/registration/locale/cs

creating build/lib/registration/locale/cs/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/cs/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo -> build/lib/registration/locale/cs/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/cs/LC_MESSAGES/django.po -> build/lib/registration/locale/cs/LC_MESSAGES

creating build/lib/registration/locale/da

creating build/lib/registration/locale/da/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/da/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo -> build/lib/registration/locale/da/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/da/LC_MESSAGES/django.po -> build/lib/registration/locale/da/LC_MESSAGES

creating build/lib/registration/locale/de

creating build/lib/registration/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo -> build/lib/registration/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/django.po -> build/lib/registration/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES

creating build/lib/registration/locale/el

creating build/lib/registration/locale/el/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/el/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo -> build/lib/registration/locale/el/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/el/LC_MESSAGES/django.po -> build/lib/registration/locale/el/LC_MESSAGES

creating build/lib/registration/locale/en

creating build/lib/registration/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo -> build/lib/registration/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/django.po -> build/lib/registration/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES

creating build/lib/registration/locale/es

creating build/lib/registration/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo -> build/lib/registration/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES/django.po -> build/lib/registration/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES

creating build/lib/registration/locale/es_AR

creating build/lib/registration/locale/es_AR/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/es_AR/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo -> build/lib/registration/locale/es_AR/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/es_AR/LC_MESSAGES/django.po -> build/lib/registration/locale/es_AR/LC_MESSAGES

creating build/lib/registration/locale/fa

creating build/lib/registration/locale/fa/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/fa/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo -> build/lib/registration/locale/fa/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/fa/LC_MESSAGES/django.po -> build/lib/registration/locale/fa/LC_MESSAGES

creating build/lib/registration/locale/fr

creating build/lib/registration/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo -> build/lib/registration/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po -> build/lib/registration/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES

creating build/lib/registration/locale/he

creating build/lib/registration/locale/he/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/he/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo -> build/lib/registration/locale/he/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/he/LC_MESSAGES/django.po -> build/lib/registration/locale/he/LC_MESSAGES

creating build/lib/registration/locale/hr

creating build/lib/registration/locale/hr/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/hr/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo -> build/lib/registration/locale/hr/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/hr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po -> build/lib/registration/locale/hr/LC_MESSAGES

creating build/lib/registration/locale/is

creating build/lib/registration/locale/is/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/is/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo -> build/lib/registration/locale/is/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/is/LC_MESSAGES/django.po -> build/lib/registration/locale/is/LC_MESSAGES

creating build/lib/registration/locale/it

creating build/lib/registration/locale/it/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/it/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo -> build/lib/registration/locale/it/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/it/LC_MESSAGES/django.po -> build/lib/registration/locale/it/LC_MESSAGES

creating build/lib/registration/locale/ja

creating build/lib/registration/locale/ja/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/ja/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo -> build/lib/registration/locale/ja/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/ja/LC_MESSAGES/django.po -> build/lib/registration/locale/ja/LC_MESSAGES

creating build/lib/registration/locale/ko

creating build/lib/registration/locale/ko/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/ko/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo -> build/lib/registration/locale/ko/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/ko/LC_MESSAGES/django.po -> build/lib/registration/locale/ko/LC_MESSAGES

creating build/lib/registration/locale/nb

creating build/lib/registration/locale/nb/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/nb/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo -> build/lib/registration/locale/nb/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/nb/LC_MESSAGES/django.po -> build/lib/registration/locale/nb/LC_MESSAGES

creating build/lib/registration/locale/nl

creating build/lib/registration/locale/nl/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/nl/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo -> build/lib/registration/locale/nl/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/nl/LC_MESSAGES/django.po -> build/lib/registration/locale/nl/LC_MESSAGES

creating build/lib/registration/locale/pl

creating build/lib/registration/locale/pl/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/pl/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo -> build/lib/registration/locale/pl/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/pl/LC_MESSAGES/django.po -> build/lib/registration/locale/pl/LC_MESSAGES

creating build/lib/registration/locale/pt

creating build/lib/registration/locale/pt/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/pt/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo -> build/lib/registration/locale/pt/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/pt/LC_MESSAGES/django.po -> build/lib/registration/locale/pt/LC_MESSAGES

creating build/lib/registration/locale/pt_BR

creating build/lib/registration/locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo -> build/lib/registration/locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES/django.po -> build/lib/registration/locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES

creating build/lib/registration/locale/ru

creating build/lib/registration/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo -> build/lib/registration/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/django.po -> build/lib/registration/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES

creating build/lib/registration/locale/sl

creating build/lib/registration/locale/sl/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/sl/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo -> build/lib/registration/locale/sl/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/sl/LC_MESSAGES/django.po -> build/lib/registration/locale/sl/LC_MESSAGES

creating build/lib/registration/locale/sr

creating build/lib/registration/locale/sr/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/sr/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo -> build/lib/registration/locale/sr/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/sr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po -> build/lib/registration/locale/sr/LC_MESSAGES

creating build/lib/registration/locale/sv

creating build/lib/registration/locale/sv/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/sv/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo -> build/lib/registration/locale/sv/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/sv/LC_MESSAGES/django.po -> build/lib/registration/locale/sv/LC_MESSAGES

creating build/lib/registration/locale/tr_TR

creating build/lib/registration/locale/tr_TR/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/tr_TR/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo -> build/lib/registration/locale/tr_TR/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/tr_TR/LC_MESSAGES/django.po -> build/lib/registration/locale/tr_TR/LC_MESSAGES

creating build/lib/registration/locale/zh_CN

creating build/lib/registration/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo -> build/lib/registration/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES/django.po -> build/lib/registration/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES

creating build/lib/registration/locale/zh_TW

creating build/lib/registration/locale/zh_TW/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/zh_TW/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo -> build/lib/registration/locale/zh_TW/LC_MESSAGES

copying registration/locale/zh_TW/LC_MESSAGES/django.po -> build/lib/registration/locale/zh_TW/LC_MESSAGES

running install_lib

creating /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/test_app

error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/test_app': Permission denied

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python3.4 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_alex/django-registration-redux/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-qi55qyaf-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_alex/django-registration-redux
Storing debug log for failure in /home/alex/.pip/pip.log
```

Comment: Next time use [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com), please

Comment: No, do not use Pastebin; it's against the rules. Links to external sites may break over time.

Answer (score 0):

Run as superuser as follows:

```
sudo pip install django-registration-redux
```

Answer (score 0):

```
error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/test_app': Permission denied
```

This is telling you that you do not have permission to write to /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/.

Perhaps try running as root with 
    sudo